# 1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 5.7.21' failed

Tags: mysql, sql

Can't install MySQL server on Windows 10,
part of the log:

```
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.7, Name: installed, Value: #1
1: Action 23:23:09: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 23:23:10: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: RunPostInstall
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.7 2: {3FAF469E-B671-4ED9-AB0D-CF8D41E35319} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 5.7.21' failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Soooo, if you're having this problem, just install MySQL without server files.